How to delete form data from database?
I can add and update data on form into in the database, but l am unable to delete the saved data from the same database. My problem is how to delete database records base on form textbox value.
Component.ts
public orderForm = new FormGroup({
  Id: new FormControl(), 
  Name: new FormControl(),
  Address: new FormControl(),   
});

delete() {
 if(this.orderForm.valid){
  this.service2.deleteData(this.orderForm.value).subscribe((result) =>{
    console.log(result);
    this.toastr.success('Record Deleted Successful');
  });  
 }
 else
 {
  this.toastr.error('Please Select Record to Delete ');  
 }   
}

SharedService.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { employeeData } from './data-model';

const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({
 "Content-Type": "application/json"
})};

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'})
export class SharedService {

public APIUrl= "http://localhost:5000/api/5mployees";

constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
 
}

getcropplanting(state: any): Observable<any> {
 console.log(state);
 return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl);
}

addRecord(state: any): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.post<any>(this.APIUrl, state.data, httpOptions);
}

updateRecord(state: any): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.put<any>(this.APIUrl, state.data, httpOptions);
}

deleteData(id: number): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.delete(`${this.APIUrl}/${id}`)
 }
}


You should show your implementation on back-end side API that removes data from DB. Also please provide more details such as what error you get.

Besides, your deleteData in service is with 1 parameter: id, but you provide the object for your form to call that method. You should provide this.orderForm.value.Id.

@Yong you have been of great help. Thank you

The deleteData from the SharedService expects 1 argument with the number type. Currently, you provide the value from the this.orderForm.value which is an object and you will get the compilation error.
Instead, you should provide this.orderForm.value.Id to the caller.
this.service2.deleteData(this.orderForm.value.Id).subscribe((result) =>{
  console.log(result);
  this.toastr.success('Record Deleted Successful');
});  

